# Remove the x-powered-by in a React app hosted in Vercel

Tags: reactjs, http-headers, create-react-app, vercel, helmet.js

I want to remove the `x-powered-by: express` from my React App that is hosted in Vercel, how is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

I know that in the server side I can do this using Helmet, but in react / Vercel I don't have any clue.